# get the current selected language of the language bar in windows 7

Tags: c#, c++, windows-7

I am writing a key logger in windows 7 ( using SetWindowsHookEx ) and I need to know the correct keyboardLayout for the key being pressed. 
I tried getting the keyboardLayout from the ForegroundWindow and this works fine in most cases but in Internet Explorer 9 it doesn't work as expected (it returns the wrong layout ).
I thought about getting the layout from the language bar ( because it shows the language of the window that is currently being typed on ) but I don't know how to retrieve this data.
Maybe there is a registry key with this data or I can ask the language bar window for its text.
Any ideas ?

Comment: You are writing a what?! What exactly is the purpose of your keylogger?

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't  [GetKeyboardLayout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646296%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) of WinApi do what you want?

Comment: I does but it requires a thread id and I tried getting that thread using  GetWindowThreadProcessId but it the Internet Explorer 9 case it gives the wrong result

Comment: How can I get the window with the keyboard focus ?

Comment: Argh... Known issue. Here is an article http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/10/06/8969399.aspx

Comment: You may have to combine http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646292(v=vs.85).aspx GetActiveWindow().

Comment: But you can get thread from which the keyboard focus by using GetGUIThreadInfo with first parameter as NULL

Comment: At least now you can reformulate your question =)