# How to get the selected language in C# when more than one culture is installed?

Tags: c#, cultureinfo, culture

Seems there is two cultures(languages) installed on the Windows. For example en-us (English) and Chinese and we can changed the language by Alt+Shift as you know. I need to show the selected language. For example if Chinese is selected when I click on a button on windows form, a massage box show me Chinese is selected. Like this:

```
if(culture == "en_us")
{
    messagebox.show("English");
}
else
{
    messageBox.show("Chinese");*
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get current language in cultureinfo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4208244/get-current-language-in-cultureinfo)

Comment: @gravity This only show me the additional installed language and not the selected current language.

Comment: `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture`?  `InstalledUICulture` should be the list, per se... not the other way around?  The same question has yet another answer, detailing how to change the culture for that specific thread-only : `System.Globalization.CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture=CultureInfo.InstalledUICulture;`

Answer (score 1):

Use CultureInfo object that represents the culture used by the current thread.

```
CultureInfo currentCulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at [get the current selected language of the language bar in windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6135776/get-the-current-selected-language-of-the-language-bar-in-windows-7) and modern WinAPI docs.

And at this doc https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.keyboardlayoutid(v=vs.110).aspx

If I understand you correctly it will help you to achieve you goal (KeyboardLayoutId will probably lead you there, sorry, I can't test it right now).